# Route to same React Component even if no path parameter is provided

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to render the same component in my application even if no path parameter is provided:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/productInfoList/:product"
      component={ProductInfoList}
     />
  </Switch>
```

However, if there is no ":product" parameter provided in the URL, the component does not get rendered. Is there a way to render the same "ProductInfoList" component, even if no path parameter is provided?

I feel there must be an efficient way of doing it than redeclaring a new route just for `path="/productInfoList"` altogether.

Comment: sounds like your component can work without the /:product pram, so remove it from path and chack in the component if path pram has been passed and if so do your logic

Answer (score 0):

hi there you can  the a route without a pram
and then just pass in the history.push or link

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/template',
  search: '?query=abc',
  state: { detail: response.data }
})
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/template',
      search: '?query=abc',
      state: { detail: response.data }
    }}> My Link </Link>
```

as you can see here you can pass a state if you want to get the data you can use
props.location.state.detail
like this you can track if you get a state or not and then use it how you want